# Passing a partial application as an argument of an other function with no overhead

Tags: c++, performance, template

I am trying to find a way to pass a partial application as an argument of an other application with no overhead. I think I have find a way to do it (which might be dirty). The templated structure "partial_add" is kind of a partial version of add2. I am passing the type "partial_add" as template argument to another function.

```
void add2(int *a, int *b){
    *a += *b;
}

template <int *a>
struct partial_add{
    static void method(int *b){
        add2(a,b);
    }
};

// Apply a function to every elements of b
template <typename FUNCTION>
void apply_array(int *b){
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        FUNCTION::method(&b[i]);
    }
    
} 

int main(){
    // a required to be static so that &a can be passed as a template argument
    static int a;
    int b[100];


    apply_array<partial_add<&a>>(b);

}
```

What I like about that solution is that if you look at it in godbolt you will see that at optimization level 1 (In real life I use -O3), the line "apply_array<partial_add<&a>>(b)" becomes :

```
.L4:
        add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx]
        add     rdx, 4
        cmp     rdx, rax
        jne     .L4
```

So the compiler understood what I was trying to do.
What I don't like about this solution is the fact that I have to declare "a" static, it bothers me a bit. In theory it's not a problem for my program, in practice it's kind of bad.

I tried to use partial application with lambda expression but at the end there was indeed an overhead (a call for exemple).

Maybe you have an idea of what I could do about that.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers

Comment: You might be looking for something called "expression templates".  Boost has a fairly old library for that, but the technique in general is explained in many books and is a technique used in libraries such as matrix arithmetic.

Comment: Hmm, your `partial_add` can be a lambda, not a template.  You are wanting the capture behavior and lamenting that template arguments don't do that well.  Partial application is a common use for lambdas, as well as the old `bind` functions (now deprecated).

Comment: @JDługosz Thanks for the reply. The thing is I have trouble passing the lambda expression to the "apply_array" function. For exemple if I have the lambda : "auto partial_addLambda = [a](int *b1){
    return add2(a,b1);
    };" in the main, I have to give it as a function argument.

Comment: Model it after standard algorithms like this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

Comment: @TobySpeight Hello, I modified the title and the code a bit so that it's a little bit more understandable !

Comment: According to your other comments, this isn't your real code (where you are using something different to `partial_add`), making this _example code_ that's not representative of what you actually need, and making the answers inapplicable.

Comment: Is the actual problem you are trying to solve creating a calculator?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code, this example is simply:

```
int b[100];
// ... the values for b are filled in with interesting things
using std::begin; using std::end;

int a = std::accumulate (begin(b), end(b), 0);
```

as the default operation to `accumulate` is to sum the values.

But to illustrate how you would write it, instead of `+=` with a bound value for the left hand side, it uses `+` and passes the current total in and gets the updated total as the result.

```
constexpr auto add= [](int left, int right){ return left+right; };
//...
int a = std::accumulate (begin(b), end(b), 0, add);
```

I don't know why you are making everything pointers or pointers to pointers, or dynamically allocating the array or the result `a` for that matter!

Comment: Hello, thank you for the rely. Unfortunalty the addition was just an exemple to try to explain my problem (my problem is more generic than that !). I am trying to pass a partial application as an argument of a function without any overhead. I just which I could do it compile time without having to declare my variable static (I have to do it like that for now to pass the adress of a as a template argument in partial_add). You are 100% right, the pointer to pointers and the dynamic allocation are pointless and not relevant to the comprehension of my problem, I modified the code.

Comment: I wish I could do what you said with lambda expression (instead of making a strange struct which "holds" the adress of a as a template argument). But I am not sure on how to pass this lambda expression to "lambda_array" with no overheads. Giving it as a template would be nice but I feel that I will have the same problem with a having to be static.

Comment: @adsu, _example code_ is off-topic here on Code Review for exactly this reason.  You should be posting a real use of your function so that reviewers aren't wasting their time and yours proposing simplifications that don't transfer from the example.

Comment: How significant is passing a normal parameter or constructing the lambda's capture state?  Anyway, Inlining removes that overhead from the specific call.